# How do I match a multiline pattern using Regexp::Grammars?

Tags: regex, perl, grammar, regexp-grammars

I'm new to Regexp::Grammars, and am having trouble matching a multi-line pattern. I have this input:

```
my $text = <<EOD;
HEADER:
This is a multi-line section, because the
second line is down here.

EOD
```

and this grammar:

```
use Regexp::Grammars;
my $parser = qr{
  <nocontext:>
  <doc>
  <rule: doc>           <[section]>+
  <rule: section>       <label> : <text> (\n\n | $)
  <token: label>        [A-Z0-9_&/ -]+
  <token: text>         [^\n]*
}xms;
```

I'm only matching the first line of the section, but I'd like to capture all text up to a blank line or end of input. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what you did wrong is tell it `<text>` cannot contain newlines, so it doesn't.  What isn't so obvious is the correct solution.

Comment: @cjm, yes, good point. I should have shown my other attempts. I had tried defining <text> as .*, but that ate up everything, including subsequent sections. I though .*? might work, but that stopped at the first newline.

Comment: @Jeff, because `.` doesn't match `\n` unless you use `/s`, so `(?s:.*?)` would probably work. Or maybe `.+(?:\n.+)*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to change `<text>` as follows:

```
<token: text>         (?:(?!\n\n).)*
```

This matches 0 or more characters that are not a newline followed by another newline.  It's probably not the best possible solution, but it works.

Comment: thanks, that worked great! I had forgotten about look-aheads.